# Python: List all the files names containing the string as in its column name

Tags: python, python-3.8

I am new to python. I have a folder with many sub folders containing Parquet files of 100+GB data. some of the file size is also in GBs. I am trying to list all the files that contains column name like "Email"(at start, end or mid) case=False. The output should be in a .txt file. I have tried the below code but its not working properly.Can someone help?

```
inp=["Email","Mail"]
    op=[]
    for elem in listOfFiles:
        if(elem.endswith(".parquet")):
            full_path=elem
            filename = elem.split(".")
            filename = filename[0]
            pfile=pq.read_table(elem)
           stri  =  str(pfile.schema)
            for val in inp:
                if(stri.count(val)>0):
                    op.append(full_path)
```

Comment: What is the error you get? The syntax seems to be off, but I’m not sure if this is because of copy paste or not.

Comment: the syntax may contain many issues. I need to list all .Parquet files from all folders and subfolders containing the string in its column name.

Answer (score 0):

```
inp=["Email","Mail"]
op=[]
for elem in listOfFiles:
  if(elem.endswith(".parquet")):
    full_path=elem
    filename = elem.split(".")
    filename = filename[0]
    pfile=pq.read_table(elem)
    stri = str(pfile.schema)
    for val in inp:
      if(stri.count(val)>0):
        op.append(full_path)
```

Try that. If you get an error, please post it here and I can further troubleshoot.

Comment: This works only when the search string is the beginning of the column name and not at mid or end.

Comment: Can you post an example of the line within the file that has the search string? You might need to use a refer for this? However, I am not sure unless I see some sample data.